# javascript save word if found in string

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, variables, include

I am learning Javascript and have a quick question. I want to search a string for a specific word or phrase. If that word/phrase exists in the the string. I want to save it to a variable to be used later.

Code I have so far is as follows:

```
var str = "This is a test sentence";
var hasTest = str.includes("test");

if(hasTest == true)
{
    //save the word that was searched
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript variables are generally used to store value you want to reuse later. When you search for "test", you already know the matched string will be "test", so you can set `const foundString = "test"`, but it won't be of great use.

You can also save the variable prior to searching the string, which is generally good practice, in case you need to change the search string:

```
const str = "This is a test sentence";
const searchText = "test";
const hasTest = str.includes(searchText);

if (hasTest)
{
    // The found word, "test", is in the searchTest variable
}
```

You would most likely need to implement such code logic if you searched for different words, say for example "test" and "foo". You could then use a RegExp ([Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)) to match any of the two words:

```
const searchExpression = new RegExp(/(test|foo)/);

const testString1 = "This is a test";
const stringMatch1 = testString1.match(searchExpression));
if (stringMatch1) {
  console.log(stringMatch1[0]); // > test
}

const testString2 = "This is a foo";
const stringMatch2 = testString2.match(searchExpression));
if (stringMatch2) {
  console.log(stringMatch2[0]); // > foo
}

const testString3 = "This is a bar";
const stringMatch3 = testString3.match(searchExpression)); // = null
if (stringMatch3) { // null evaluates to false
  console.log(stringMatch3[0]); // is not run
}
```

Also, please note that I have been using `const` to declare my constant variables (and `let` to declare the others). This is generally considered best practice (see [this link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/) for an explanation of the difference).

Final sidenote: `str.includes` returns a boolean, which can be directly evaluated in an if statement: `hasTest == true` gives the same result as `hasTest`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! that clarified a bit